# Header file etiquette

Tags: c++, c

When I am creating a header file, that is going to be used by multiple developers, is it considered good programming practice to make that header file self-sufficient in terms of all the definitions and declarations used in it.

For example:

Header file 1 : types.h

```
#ifndef TYPES_H
#define TYPES_H
typedef unsigned int uint16
#endif
```

Header file 2: myheader.h

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H
uint16 myfunc(void);
#endif
```

I have used uint16 in myheader.h without including types.h . So if anyone wants to include myheader.h in their source file they should first include "types.h" and then include "myheader.h". So this is actually forcing the developer to include header files in a specific order. I had always thought of this as bad practice, but I came across some code today at my company where to get a function declared in one file you need to include at least 4 other header files. So now I am confused, am I missing something, is there any place where this would be considered expected behaviour.

Comment: I can not think of a single situation where it would be considered acceptable to have headers that require other headers to be included in client code. It sounds like the code you found is broken.

Comment: @juanchopanza so that's why libc is broken. In several implementations, you have to e.g. include sys/types.h before sys/stat.h because struct stat is declared only in types.h. Sigh.

Comment: I can't add much to the answers already given, but it is a great mistake to think that if you see something done in the code at your company it must not be a rotten practice.

Comment: As an aside, why are you not using the fixed width types defined in `stdint.h`?

Comment: @juanchopanze: it is however a common situation.

Comment: @BlankXavier sadly, it is all too common. However, we shouldn't strive to emulate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polluting the global namespace with unnecessary types is bad practice. The best you can do is provide forward-declarations where possible, and `include` other files where necessary. In your simplified case, you should include the header that defines `uint16` in every header that uses it.

If, for example, you can forward-declare the type, this is to be prefered. The rationale is that a forward-declaration is enough if you don't actually use the type. And if you do use the type, **you** should include the header where it's declared explicitly.

Comment: Disagree. Then you have forward declarations everywhere. What if you wanted to change a type. You'd have to hunt down all its forward declarations everywhere.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista not really, no. If you changed its name, you'd have to do that anyway. And if you don't change its name, there's no problem.

Comment: I often use two headers: a X_fdw.h and a X.h. If you only need the declarations, include the forward header, otherwise include the full header. This also makes it easier to change the type of X later on.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore and the OP, a good rule of thumb: Forward declare the type when you are only using a pointer to the type in the header.  Include the other header when you are using the type itself.

Comment: @JoshPetitt it's not restricted to that. You don't need a full definition for a type if you're using a reference, a return type or a parameter.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, oops I was speaking only for C.  However, from my memory, I thought you needed the definition for return types and parameters. Otherwise how does the compiler know how much to push/pop?

Comment: @JoshPetitt :) It only needs to push/pop if you actually use the function. And if you use the function, you need the full definition of the types, right? Which implies inclusion.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I don't understand your statement about using the function, this shouldn't affect the OP's requirements (unless you just like writing cruft that no one will ever use).  You can use the data hiding pattern where the user never knows the type definition (fairly common in C).  Also, depending on when the type is defined, you may be able to compile without knowing the type (if you only use a pointer) and only a link time does the value need to be defined.  This weak association can be used the Bridge pattern.  I think the rule of thumb I provided is pretty good for most situations.

Answer (score 4):

You'd better just create some include guards and then `#include "types.h"` into myheader.h. Don't make others think (at least not this way).

Answer (score 3):

TO be specific in answering your question: YES, a header file should be self-sufficient.  It should include every header file that is needed *to allow it to compile*.

In general, most modern library's have guards in place so that the header file(s) are only "seen" by the compiler once.  First come, first serve.  So don't get too hung-up on that (though it never hurts to verify).

Answer (score 1):

A public header should provide all of the definitions necessary to use the interfaces that it exposes, and nothing more.

Comment: +1 for Stephen on the definitions.  If you have a header that defines a function and that function uses a non-intrinsic datatype, then you should include that #include within the header guard (not outside of it generally).  Also, C header etiquette would prefer using standard types for public interfaces, so like Stephen said, prefer <stdint.h>

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a matter of convention, but in almost all similar cases `myheader.h` #includes `types.h` at its very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

All headers should be self-sufficient, unless explicitly stated with #error unless some defines are defined.

I always put the matching header for a CPP-file as the first include to make sure they are always compilable.